# Как сделать поиск по нескольким ключевым словам и вывод всех слов?

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, winforms

имеются две проблемы,

1. Хочу сделать поиск по нескольким ключивым словам, а не только из
   одного слова в richTextBox2. К примеру через запятую или пробел.
2. При попытки вывести все найденные слова, он выводит только одно в
   richTextBox3, Windows Form, а в консоли все идет гладно, пробывал
   запускать через поток.

   ```
   string TextFind = richTextBox1.Text;

   foreach (string row in Regex.Split(TextFind, @"(\b\w*\w*\b)"))
   {
       if (Regex.IsMatch(row, richTextBox2.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) //Принимает только одно слово ключевое слово.
           //Console.WriteLine(row.Trim());

           richTextBox3.Text = row.ToString(); // Вывод всего одного найденного слова, как сделать вывод всех?
   }
   ```

Буду рад, если вы мне поможете. Заодно получу плюс знания в копилку.

Comment: `richTextBox3.Text += row.ToString();` ?

Comment: Он выводит вообще  весь текст. А не ключевые слова.

Comment: Если вам нужны совпадения с регуляркой, то вам [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: tym32167, Я это читал немного, там вроде не написано про то, как сделать несколько ключевых слов. - if (Regex.IsMatch(row, richTextBox2.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) Он принимает только одно ключевое слово richTextBox2.Text, к примеру хочу сделать чтобы он принимал несколько ключ слов, через запятую или пробел.

Comment: тогда вам надо одно из двух: 1) разбить текст на слова и проверять каждое слово - не ключевое ли оно 2) из ваших ключевых слов составить большую регулярку